# Development Team not populating in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I recently got invited to an Apple Developer Team. When i log in via the `apple.developer.com` portal, I can clearly see the Apple Developer Program that I am apart of.

However, whenever I try to sign into xcode using my apple ID, I am only given the option of `Name (Personal Team)` and not the development team that I am apart of.

Has anybody had this issue before, and what are some troubleshooting steps I could take. I am an `app manager` role and have tried removing and re-linking my Apple ID and nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple accounts in the `Xcode` > `Preferences` > `Accounts` pane.  Click the `+` on the bottom left of the pane to add another account.

[image]

In your project settings, under signing, you can change your team there.

Comment: It is the same apple id though

Comment: Can you not log in via that Accounts setting screen?

Comment: I can login just fine, the problem is that my personal team is the only team that is showing -- even though i am on another specific development team

Comment: You may need the User Agent (or an Admin) to resend the team invite. You unlinking your account may have removed you from the team.  If the re-invite doesn't work, you could change your role to be a Developer rather than App Manager.

Comment: One last thing to check, you might be a part of the development portal (http://developer.apple.com), but you might not be a part of App Store Connect (https://appstoreconnect.apple.com).  You'll need to be a part of both.

Comment: Yes I am a part of both